# How can i disable to submit form with default text in input fields?

Tags: jquery, watermark

***jQuery Code :***

```
(function($){
$.fn.jgtextdefault = function(settings){
var jElements = this;
var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.jgtextdefault.defaults, settings);
return jElements.each(function(){
if($(jElements).is("input")){ jgTextDefault( $(jElements) ); }
});
function jgTextDefault(jInput){
if (jInput.val().length==0) jInput.val(settings.text);
jInput.focus(function () {
if (jInput.val()==settings.text) jInput.val('');
});
jInput.blur(function () {
if (jInput.val().length==0) jInput.val(settings.text);
});}};
$.fn.jgtextdefault.defaults = {
text: 'Default'
};
})(jQuery);
```

***Php Code :***

```
if (empty($releasedata['size'])) {
                $errors[] = '<li>'.Enter the size in GB.'</li>';
            }
if (empty($releasedata['releaseinfo'])) {
                $errors[] = '<li>'.Give more information.'</li>';
            }
        break;
```

***Html Code :***

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#defaultText-releasename').jgtextdefault({'text':'This is the default text for release name'});
      $('#defaultText-releasesize').jgtextdefault({'text':'This is the default text for release size'});

    });
  </script>
```

***Html (Input Fields) :***

```
<input id="defaultText-releasename" type="text" name="releasename" value="$releasedata[releasename]" />
```

**My Problem :**
Everything is fine with displaying default text in input fields and hide on focus. But the problem is, when i submit the form (if user/me do not type anything in input fields, then it takes the input field value as the default text.

Since you can see from above php code, i would like to display the error message if nothing typed into input fields by user. So i do not want form to be submitted with the default text in input fields...

Can someone please help me with this problem ?

Thanks in advance and regards...

Comment: do you want to use php or jquery to display error if input is empty

Comment: Well actually i just want jQuery not submit the form with default text since my current php is already displaying error messages. What i mean is, if i cancel the id from the input field (no jQuery), and if i submit the form with no text typed, then i get the error code as shown in above php code...

So i need something to disable the default text in input fields on form submit... And it will not submit the form with default text in input fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved my problem with another jQuery code which has "**clear the pre-defined text when form is submitted**" function...

This may be useful for some other users too... So here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.default').each(function(){
    var defaultVal = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).focus(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == defaultVal){
        $(this).removeClass('active').val('');
      }
    })
    .blur(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).addClass('active').val(defaultVal);
      }
    })
    .blur().addClass('active');
  });
  $('form').submit(function(){
    $('.default').each(function(){
      var defaultVal = $(this).attr('title');
      if ($(this).val() == defaultVal){
        $(this).val('');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And HTML would be as :

```
<input type="text" name="text1" value="" class="default" title="Default Text 1" />
```

All credits goes to : [DesignChemical](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/add-default-text-to-form-fields-using-jquery/)...

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use:

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function(){
     if(validate_form()){
         return true;
     }else{
       return false;
     }
});
```

validate your form inputs(here, i use my own function `validate_form()`, you can implement it as you like to check the values of your textboxes), if all OK then the function `validate_form()` return true so, the form will submit; otherwise, the from will not submitted.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, but still submitting the form with input field default text (watermark text) if i leave the field empty....

Comment: you can implement the function `validate_form()` to check the content if the text field if it is the default value then return false.

Comment: `function validate_form(){ var value = $('input[name=releasename']).val(); if(value == 'your default text'){ return false; } else{ return true; } }`

Comment: Mohamad, thanks a lot for your kind help. But i think i am doing wrong somewhere. And i am sure it's a dummy mistake... But still not working. Actually since my php is doing the validate, and i use the jquery default text function just for the description, do you know what i have to add to my php if default text is submitted ? For example, as you can see from above php code, the default text for one of the input field is "Enter the size in GB". So i think i can do it with adding a line to php ?